# asp.net disable/enable validator using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have a complex form requiring me to switch specific validators on or off depending on selections made by the user.

ValidatorEnable seems to do the job, but it seems that when I call this method it actually fires the validation process as well, without the user actually hitting the submit button.

Is that how it works?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I eventually found the best way to do this was to use the following code:

```
var validatorObject = document.getElementById('<%=ValidHasShippingLocationZip.ClientID%>');
validatorObject.enabled = false;
validatorObject.isvalid = true;
ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validatorObject);
```

Comment: it worked, I didn't use the isvalid property, I worked just with the enable or disable

Comment: Why I'm still able to submit my asp.net form while the above function works with my validators and display / hide the validator? I don't use isValid in my code behind!

Comment: @DKR make sure you find correct `validatorObject`, maybe you should use `console.log(validatorObject)` to see if the element was find correctly.

Comment: It worked, but has 1 problem, `Page.Isvalid` still returns `false` (I mean on code-behind side)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some code seems can meet your requests.
Iterate validators and enable these you needs.

```
   ValidatorEnable(validatorObj, true);
```

then clear the screen,erase the error info.

The full code snippet can be found here http://codelife.cybtamin.com/enable-and-disable-asp-net-validator-by-javascript/

Comment: Don't just post links, links die.

Comment: `ValidatorEnable(valObj, enable)` is now part of the .NET boilerplate code so this example can be used without additional code.